# Importing Maven project into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

I want to import existing Maven project into Eclipse. I found 2 ways to do it:

1. Through running from command line `mvn eclipse:eclipse`
2. To install Maven Eclipse plugin from Eclipse.

What is the difference between the both and which one is preferable?

If I install Maven Eclipse plugin through the Eclipse menu **Help -> Install New Software**, do I still need to modify my `pom.xml` to include the Maven Eclipse plugin in the plugins section?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

> I want to import existing maven project into eclipse. I found 2 ways to do it, one is through running from command line `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and another is to install maven eclipse plugin from eclipse. What is the difference between the both and which one is preferable?

The [maven-eclipse-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) is a *Maven plugin* which is one of the first plugins available with Maven 1, and one of the first plugins migrated to Maven 2. For a long time it has been the only decent way to <strike>integrate</strike>import an existing maven project with Eclipse. Actually, it doesn't provide real integration, it just generates the `.project` and `.classpath` files (it has also WTP support) from a Maven project. I've used this plugin for **years** and was very happy with it (and I've been very unsatisfied with the Eclipse plugins for Maven like [m2eclipse](http://mevenide.codehaus.org/)).

The [m2eclipse](https://repository.sonatype.org/content/sites/forge-sites/m2e/) plugin is one of the [*Eclipse plugins for Maven*](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html). It's actually the first and most mature of the projects aimed at integrating Maven within the Eclipse IDE (this has not always been the case, it was not really usable ~2 years ago, see the feedback in [Mevenide vs. M2Eclipse, Q for Eclipse/IAM](http://markmail.org/message/ii5lpnyrtxkxoltx)). But, even if I do not use things like creating a Maven project from Eclipse or the POM editor or other fancy wizards, I have to say that this plugin is now totally usable, provides very smooth integration, has nice features... In other words, I finally switched to it :) I'd now recommend it to any user (advanced or beginners).

> If I install maven eclipse plugin through the eclipse menu Help -> Install New Software, do I still need to modify my pom.xml to include the maven eclipse plugin in the plugins section?

This question is a bit confusing but the answer is no. With the m2eclipse plugin installed, just **right-click** the package explorer and **Import... > Maven projects** to import an existing maven project into Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about import, I was trying to go through new project, and it was a lot of work for little gain.  BTW, when you do this import, Eclipse leaves the files in the original location, it does not copy them to your workspace.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify the "If I install maven eclipse plugin through the eclipse menu ..." part. You cannot install Maven Eclipse Plugin to Eclipse. Maven Eclipse Plugin is a Maven plugin. It is not an Eclipse plugin. Hence, you cannot install Maven Eclipse Plugin to Eclipse. You can install the M2Eclipse plugin to Eclipse.

Comment: A ton of work for little gain. This is exactly why I think Maven is counter productive.

Answer (score 88):

I am not experienced with Eclipse or Maven so the other answers seemed a bit over complicated.

The following simpler set of steps worked for me:

***Prerequisite***: Make sure you have Maven plugin installed in your Eclipse IDE: [How to add Maven plugin to Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25993960/1971003)

1. Open Eclipse
2. Click **File** > **Import**
3. Type **Maven** in the search box under **Select an import source:**
4. Select **Existing Maven Projects**
5. Click **Next**
6. Click **Browse** and select the folder that is the root of the Maven project (probably contains the `pom.xml` file)
7. Click **Next**
8. Click **Finish**

Comment: this is actually the most recommend solution as it is based on the maven pom-configuration and not on the derived, possibly outdated eclipse .project  config

Comment: can we automate the above steps? like using powershell, is there a CLI?

Comment: Should also mention that you need the Maven plug-in for Eclipse otherwise the option won't be available.

Answer (score 18):

Using `mvn eclipse:eclipse` will just generate general eclipse configuration files, this is fine if you have a simple project; but in case of a web-based project such as servlet/jsp you need to manually add Java EE features to eclipse (WTP).

To make the project runnable via eclipse servers portion, Configure Apache for Eclipse: Download and unzip Apache Tomcat somewhere. In Eclipse Windows -> Preferences -> Servers -> Runtime Environments add (Create local server), select your version of Tomcat, Next, Browse to the directory of the Tomcat you unzipped, click Finish.

Window -> Show View -> Servers    Add the project to the server list

Answer (score 13):

I find the [m2eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) plugin to be more useful. This provides nice tools like the POM editor and creating a Maven project from within Eclipse.

Comment: Is using the m2elcipse plugin the same as using mvn eclipse:eclipse?

Comment: No, they are different. I never found the Maven eclipse:eclipse goal to be of much use. The eclipse goal is only useful if you have a development environment outside of Eclipse and you want to create an Eclipse project for it. If you just want to start a new project using Maven then use the m2eclipse plugin.

Comment: In my case I have a java project which was created using IDEA. Now I need to port it into Eclipse. So should I be using mvn eclipse:eclipse or the maven eclipse plugin?

Comment: mvn eclipse:eclipse initially and then once you have the initial project setup then you can use the m2eclipse plugin.

Comment: Even for importing a new maven project to eclipse, cant I use the File->Import->Maven Projects and select the pom.xml? In this case I dont need to use mvn eclipse:eclipse. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, you can do it that way as well.

Comment: **NO**, you don't have to use `eclipse:eclipse` initially, there is no need for that if you have m2eclipse installed. Just **Import... > Maven projects** and forget the maven-eclipse-plugin.

Answer (score 12):

Maven have a Eclipse plugin and Eclipse have a Maven plugin we are going to discus those things.when we using maven with those command line stuffs and etc when we are going through eclipse we don't want to that command line codes it have very much helpful, Maven and eclipse giving good integration ,they will work very well together  thanks for that plugins

**Step 1**: Go to the maven project. Here my project is FirstApp.(Example my project is FirstApp)

There you can see one pom.xml file, now what we want is to generate an eclipse project using that pom.xml.

**Step 2**: Use  mvn eclipse:eclipse command

**Step 3**: Verify the project

after execution of this command notice that two new files have been created

Note:-  both these files are created for Eclipse. When you open those files you will notice a "M2_REPO" class variable is generate. You want to add that class path in eclipse, otherwise eclipse will show a error.

**Step 4**: Importing eclipse project

> File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects in Workspace -> Select root directory -> Done

[More details here](http://scriptime.blogspot.in/2014/08/how-to-convert-maven-project-to-eclipse.html)

Comment: I edited the steps, but didn't understand the first paragraph well enough to edit it.  I hope you can improve it.

Comment: more or less a full answer, unlike the others.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to import a Maven project with the steps suggested above until I figured out why it was not importing:

A maven project will not import if you have another Maven project with the same artifact id. Make sure that your project's artifact ID is unique in your eclipse workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Since Eclipse Neon which contains Eclipse Maven Integration (m2e) 1.7, the preferred way is one of the following ways:

- ***File > Projects from File System...*** - This works for Eclipse projects (containing the file `.project`) as well as for non-Eclipse projects that only contain the file `pom.xml`.
- **If importing from a Git repository**, in the ***Git Repositories*** view **right-click** the repository node, one folder or multiple selected folders in the *Working Tree* and choose ***Import Projects...***. This opens the same dialog, but you don't have to select the directory.

Answer (score -1):

File » Import » Maven » Existing Maven Project » Next

http://www.websparrow.org/misc/how-to-import-maven-project-in-eclipse