# Files in src/main/resources not copied when using maven and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I use maven and eclipse (with m2eclipse) for Java projects. I usually start with

```
$ mvn archetype:create \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
  -DgroupId=com.whatever.app \
  -DartifactId=wonderapp
$ mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

and then import the project into eclipse. The build path in eclipse now contains an "Excluded: **" pattern for the `src/main/resource` path. If I put for example the log4j.properties file in `src/main/resources`, it will not be copied to the output path and hence log4j won't work properly.

[image]
<sub>(source: [skitch.com](http://img.skitch.com/20101002-8cqmxtagxeewxyj8wjej97g5q1.jpg))</sub>

After I ran `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, the .classpath file in the root directory contains this line:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources" excluding="**/*.java"/>
```

After importing in eclipse, it has changed to:

```
<classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources"/>
```

I end up having to manually remove the "**" pattern. Is there any way so that I don't have to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I use maven and eclipse (with m2eclipse) for Java projects. I usually start with (...) and then import the project into eclipse.

Why do you use `mvn eclipse:eclipse` with m2eclipse? Just create your project and then **Import... > Existing Maven Project**.

Comment: Good point. I never thought about it. I suppose I have done it this way out of habit, because I started with just maven and eclipse and only later learned about m2eclipse. Anyway, it doesn't seem to matter which import I use. The result with "Import Existing Maven Project" is the same.

Comment: @bromfiets If you import your project as a Maven project, the Maven builder *is* handling resources (which makes filtering possible) and they actually get copied to `target/classes`. In other words, things just work.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the difference between `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and "Import Maven Project". I also saw your answer to question 2061094 which was very helpful. For some reason I ended up in situations where the resources where not copied to `target/classes` and removing the ** exclude pattern reliably fixed this. However, I now have difficulties reproducing this behaviour.

Comment: +1 (for this and [question 2061094 which is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061094)). Congrats in advance for making it to 100K today ;) (in only a year! took me 2 ;) )

Comment: @VonC Thank you very much. Next one now :)