# Eclipse (Maven) Changes not being compiled/built by auto-reloader

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, spring-validation

I have the automatic reload enabled in Eclipse with the Maven project I'm currently working on.  I've noticed that changes to the application.properties file almost never trigger an automatic reload, and when it does, it appears totally random. However, I've noticed that sometimes changes to a .jsp file aren't getting pulled into the project somehow.  I actually ended up chasing a bug for the better part of an hour trying to figure out what it was from the dump on the webpage, only to find out that somehow Eclipse or Maven was not loading the most recent version of either the JSP file, or the class associated with it.

To fix the application.properties issue, i have to run a **Run as => Maven Install** every single time. I just happened to run it again as I was poking around trying to bugfix, and running Maven Install fixed the error I had in my webpage (It was a ModelAttributeMethodProcessor error). Is there some sort of configuration issue in how my project is building or something? That's the only thing I can think of, but honestly I'm not that familiar with Eclipse/Maven to really know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that Eclipse sometimes has a default setting in the build options that excludes the resources folder.  It's already been answered[in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846354/files-in-src-main-resources-not-copied-when-using-maven-and-eclipse). I just didn't know what kind of problem I was looking at, but once I found this solution it ended up being the right one for me.

Comment: Can you share the steps for changing this setting in Eclipse config?