# How can I use Eclipse to import an existing project?

Tags: eclipse, maven

It's a maven project and I've already built .classpath and .project files by maven eclipse:eclipse.
Then I put it into the eclipse workspace.
However, when I tried to click File->Import to import the project, I found that my `Import` is banned (can't be clicked) , as well `Export`.

I'm new to Eclipse, so I'm not sure where the problem is. 
Hope to get some useful solution~~thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by import is banned?

Comment: If the item can be clicked, its font color is black. Now Import is grey. I cannot choose or click it.

Comment: If this is 'Import / Existing project into workspace' grayed entries usually means Eclipse already knows about the project. You might need to run 'File / Refresh' to update things completely.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to import it as a Maven project into eclipse?
I suggest [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/download/) to import the project.

There is e.g. here a topic which might help you
[Importing maven project into eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2061645/1902598)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use m2eclipse too. But my problem is not about the maven.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I downloaded the new Eclipse from www.eclipse.org instead of ubuntu apt source. Then everything is ok. I wondered that if it may be a bug.