# How to make Eclipse/SparkJava/Maven work together?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spark-java

I have downloaded maven through apt-get, I have maven integration installed on Eclipse.
I have pom.xml with spark dependency set. My project compiles and when I hit run I receive this output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building mc437-web 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.105s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 10 10:56:15 PDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/59M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What do I need to have my app running on localhost? What goal/profile I have to set on Maven?

Answer (score 1):

You need a class with a main method and which defines some routes. Then you can right click and run that class or run it from the command line.

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      get(new Route("/hello") {
         @Override
         public Object handle(Request request, Response response) {
            return "Hello World!";
         }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build your Spark project with Maven including all dependencies (for example, build one jar file), you can use [Apache Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). So, you can add to pom.xml such plugin definition:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>attached</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <configuration>
        <finalName>%JAR_FILE_NAME%</finalName>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>%JAR_FILE_NAME_DESCIPTOR%</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>%FULL_MAIN_CLASS_NAME%</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

And for running you project you can just run jar:

```
java -jar %JAR_NAME%
```

As for integration with Eclipse - you can use **mvn eclipse:eclipse** in command line, or use Maven plugin for Eclipse, and chose in menu "File -> Import". See more information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061094/importing-maven-project-into-eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

Using SparkJava v2.5.5, the code looks like this:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Spark.get("/hello", new Route() {
           public Object handle(Request request, Response response) {
               return "Hello World!";
           }
       });
}
```

To test, run the java application and call in your browser http://localhost:4567/hello