# Install maven plugin in eclipse juno

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to install maven 1.5 in eclipse unfortunately I am getting errors like:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.5.0.20140606-0033 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.5.0.20140606-0033)
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.5.0.20140606-0033 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.5.0.20140606-0033) requires 'bundle com.google.guava [14.0.1,16.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.5.0.20140606-0033 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.5.0.20140606-0033)
    To: org.eclipse.m2e.core [1.5.0.20140606-0033]
```

Comment: Are you installing it through eclipse marketplace?

Comment: yes in eclipse juno 4.2

Answer (score 56):

EClipse juno doesnt support maven 1.5..still they have not added capability of 1.5

so try 1.4 or 1.3

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.4

**MAVEN INSTALLATION**

OPTION 1 :

1. Open Eclipse IDE
2. Click Help -> Install New Software...
3. Click Add button at top right corner
4. At pop up: fill up Name as "M2Eclipse" and Location as       http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.4
5. Now click OK
   After that installation would be started.

OPTION 2 :-

1. Open Eclipse
2. Go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace
3. Search by Maven
4. Click "Install" button at "Maven Integration for Eclipse" section
5. Follow the instruction step by step

After successful installation do the followings in Eclipse:

1. Go to Window --> Preferences
2. Observe, Maven is enlisted at left panel

Finally,

1. Click on an existing project
2. Select Configure -> Convert to Maven Project

Comment: Version 1.4 http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.4 works fine for Eclipse juno

Comment: Thanks bro!  http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3 is valid for Eclipse Juno 4.2.

Answer (score 6):

This is because maven 1.5 is not compatible with eclipse juno.
So we need to use maven 1.4 or 1.3

Steps to install maven 1.4 is below

1. Click Help in eclipse
2. Install New Software
3. Url for the location of site is "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases"
4. Uncheck the checkbox "Show only the latest versions of available software"
   if do not uncheck the checkbox it will only latest version and do not show maven 1.4.
5. Select m2e and slf4j of 1.4 version and click next.

**Note:** maven v 1.3 is compatible, correct url for juno: download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3

Comment: maven v 1.3 is compatible, correct url for juno: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3

Answer (score 3):

If all the above options don't work, then first install the WST plugin in your eclipse.

In order to do that, in Eclipse Juno, go to `Install New Software > Add`, under `Name` place `Juno` and under `Location URL` insert `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno`.

Then, select `WST Server Adapters` under `Web, XML, Java, ...` (last option of the list).

Accept licensing agreement and restart Eclipse.

Then resume the usual procedure to install Maven.

Comment: Thanks ! Helped. Previously maven was not getting installed. After downloading WST Server adapter first it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Choose menu **`Help \ Install New Software...`**, then add this repository link:

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.2/1.2.0.20120903-1050/

Then install for Eclipse WTP (Web Tool Platform) Juno 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the option "Select only the latest version of this software", so that versions of the plugin compatible to your eclipse will be displayed, you can select one of them.

Answer (score -1):

`download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3` has worked for 
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

Thanks