# Unable to install m2e-wtp on eclipse juno

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno, m2e

1) Error message -

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for WTP 1.0.1.20130911-1545 (org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.20130911-1545)
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP 1.0.1.20130911-1545 (org.eclipse.m2e.wtp 1.0.1.20130911-1545) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jst.jee.web 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for WTP 1.0.1.20130911-1545 (org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.20130911-1545)
    To: org.eclipse.m2e.wtp [1.0.1.20130911-1545]

This is while importing maven's poms directly. Whats the impact if not installed?

2) Is system admin access required on the box to uninstall 'default'plugins and softwares in eclipse juno?

Comment: it would be much easier to use eclipse with maven embeded :)

Comment: which means a m2e plugin installed, and the maven projects to be 'ímported' from the pom.xmls directly?

Comment: Refer this Post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454374/install-maven-plugin-in-eclipse-juno/25993960#25993960

Answer (score 0):

Removed this eclipse plugin and I am able to import the project's poms as well.
(one of the classic cases compatibility of different plugin's version on the IDE)