# CXF Web Service Client generation in Maven failed

Tags: web-services, maven, jakarta-ee, wsdl, cxf

This is my first use of Maven and I am trying to generate a client from a WSDL.
I created a Maven Project and downloaded a pom.xml file from a similar project then I ran mvn assembly:assembly command build to generate the stubs but the compilation doesn't work and it generate an error.

This is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.logicsector</groupId>
  <artifactId>weather-client</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SOAP weather client</name>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>weather-client</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Generate Java classes from WSDL during build -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/weather.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Add generated sources - avoids having to copy generated sources to build location -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${basedir}/target/generated/src/main/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Build the JAR with dependencies -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!-- Build with Java 1.5 -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.5</source>
                        <target>1.5</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

And this is the error that I get

> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [WARNING]  [WARNING] Some problems
>   were encountered while building the effective model for
>   com.logicsector:weather-client:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [WARNING]
>   'build.plugins.plugin.version' for
>   org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 61,
>   column 21 [WARNING]  [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these
>   problems because they threaten the stability of your build. [WARNING] 
>   [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer
>   support building such malformed projects. [WARNING]  [INFO]
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building SOAP weather client 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO]  [INFO] >>> maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:assembly
>   (default-cli) @ weather-client >>> [INFO]  [INFO] ---
>   cxf-codegen-plugin:2.1.2:wsdl2java (generate-sources) @ weather-client
>   --- mars 23, 2015 3:11:05 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing
>   org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext@466d9e6c: display name
>   [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext@466d9e6c]; startup
>   date [Mon Mar 23 15:11:05 GMT+01:00 2015]; root of context hierarchy
>   mars 23, 2015 3:11:05 PM
>   org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext getConfigResources
>   INFO: No cxf.xml configuration file detected, relying on defaults.
>   mars 23, 2015 3:11:05 PM
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
>   obtainFreshBeanFactory INFO: Bean factory for application context
>   [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext@466d9e6c]:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7f85e8ac
>   mars 23, 2015 3:11:06 PM
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker
>   postProcessAfterInitialization INFO: Bean
>   'org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor' is not eligible
>   for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not
>   eligible for auto-proxying) mars 23, 2015 3:11:06 PM
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker
>   postProcessAfterInitialization INFO: Bean
>   'org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor' is not eligible
>   for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not
>   eligible for auto-proxying) mars 23, 2015 3:11:06 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory
>   preInstantiateSingletons INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7f85e8ac:
>   defining beans
>   [cxf,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.resource.ResourceManager,org.apache.cxf.configuration.Configurer,org.apache.cxf.binding.BindingFactoryManager,org.apache.cxf.transport.DestinationFactoryManager,org.apache.cxf.transport.ConduitInitiatorManager,org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLManager,org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseManager,org.apache.cxf.workqueue.WorkQueueManager,org.apache.cxf.buslifecycle.BusLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerRegistry,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.transports.http.QueryHandlerRegistry,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.EndpointResolverRegistry,org.apache.cxf.headers.HeaderManager,org.apache.cxf.catalog.OASISCatalogManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServiceContractResolverRegistry,org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WebServiceContextResourceResolver,org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WebServiceContextImpl,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.customEditorConfigurer,org.apache.cxf.binding.xml.XMLBindingFactory,org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.AddressingAssertionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.AddressingPolicyInterceptorProvider,org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.UsingAddressingAssertionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.HTTPClientAssertionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.HTTPServerAssertionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.NoOpPolicyInterceptorProvider,org.apache.cxf.transport.http.ClientOnlyHTTPTransportFactory];
>   root of factory hierarchy mars 23, 2015 3:11:10 PM
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
>   INFO: Closing
>   org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext@466d9e6c: display name
>   [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext@466d9e6c]; startup
>   date [Mon Mar 23 15:11:05 GMT+01:00 2015]; root of context hierarchy
>   mars 23, 2015 3:11:10 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry
>   destroySingletons INFO: Destroying singletons in
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7f85e8ac:
>   defining beans
>   [cxf,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.resource.ResourceManager,org.apache.cxf.configuration.Configurer,org.apache.cxf.binding.BindingFactoryManager,org.apache.cxf.transport.DestinationFactoryManager,org.apache.cxf.transport.ConduitInitiatorManager,org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLManager,org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseManager,org.apache.cxf.workqueue.WorkQueueManager,org.apache.cxf.buslifecycle.BusLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerRegistry,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.transports.http.QueryHandlerRegistry,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.EndpointResolverRegistry,org.apache.cxf.headers.HeaderManager,org.apache.cxf.catalog.OASISCatalogManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServiceContractResolverRegistry,org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WebServiceContextResourceResolver,org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WebServiceContextImpl,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.customEditorConfigurer,org.apache.cxf.binding.xml.XMLBindingFactory,org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.AddressingAssertionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.AddressingPolicyInterceptorProvider,org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.UsingAddressingAssertionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.HTTPClientAssertionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.HTTPServerAssertionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.NoOpPolicyInterceptorProvider,org.apache.cxf.transport.http.ClientOnlyHTTPTransportFactory];
>   root of factory hierarchy [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 9.122s [INFO] Finished at: Mon Mar 23 15:11:10
>   GMT+01:00 2015 [INFO] Final Memory: 21M/311M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.1.2:wsdl2java (generate-sources)
>   on project weather-client: Execution generate-sources of goal
>   org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.1.2:wsdl2java failed: Illegal
>   character in opaque part at index 2:
>   D:\gireveWorkSpace\weather-client/src/main/wsdl/weather.wsdl -> [Help
>   1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run
>   Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to
>   enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about
>   the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException

I am using Eclipse Juno and I configured Maven successfully, can you help me please to find the solution.

Comment: why do you want to use pretty old CXF version and JDK version 1.5 and is your mvn using jdk 1.5

Comment: Hi Karthik, I am using Eclipse Juno and it isn't compatible with the recent version of Maven so I am using Maven 1.4 and this version use the old CXF, this is what I think but I am a newbie so I will be grateful for any help !

Comment: Eclipse Juno support Maven 3,

Comment: I tried to install Maven 1.5 but I got errors then I searched and find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454374/install-maven-plugin-in-eclipse-juno

Comment: Its not the maven version its plugin version which supports maven tasks. The plugin is called m2e,

Comment: thank you for this clarification ! so do you think if I download Maven 3 I will get my program to run with this pom ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could use below pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.logicsector</groupId>
  <artifactId>weather-client</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SOAP weather client</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <cxf.version>2.7.5</cxf.version>
        <slfj.version>1.7.5</slfj.version>
        <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slfj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slfj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slfj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[2.7,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/weather.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/ServiceManagement.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven compiler -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

You could change cxf version based on the requirement and jdk version in properties tag. Though the version you are talking about is maven eclipse plugin (m2e), however eclipse supports maven version 3, and more over dependencies are independent of maven version.

Another point worth noting directory structure, wsdl directory in configuration is outside the classpath. In maven by default the `src/main/java`,`src/main/resources` are the classpath(this is also considered during packaging). Hence modified your cxf plugin configuration accordingly

Comment: thanks Karthik, I will consider those advices when I get to use Maven but for now I couldn't even install it ! I installed the Maven 3 but I can't install the recent plug in ! this error is reported in the Maven Market 
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/error/report/2241251

Comment: You need not install the latest m2e plugin, those plugin might not be compitibile with older version. Use m2e plugin version 1.4 itself.

Comment: That's what I did in first place ! but now I am downloading Eclipse Luna to use it