# Issue faced while installing m2e on eclipse juno

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium

Issue faced while installing m2e on eclipse juno
Details 
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.6.2.20150902-0002 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.6.2.20150902-0002)

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454374/install-maven-plugin-in-eclipse-juno

Comment: Thanks now it maven is installing in my system

Comment: @Soorapadman maybe add an answer