# Include different class folders to library : Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classpath, eclipse-classpath

I have imported a `Java` Project. It contains various folders and each folder has its own `output folder` for `class files`. So I am unable to figure out that how to add these output folders to the build path. If I am not adding these to the build path, eclipse is unable to get the class files. And if I am adding these as Class Folder, I am getting the error :

```
Source folder cannot output to Library
```

Project is a `maven` project.
Can someone help me in figuring out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not a 100%-sure if i got you correctly:

*"its own `output folder` for `class files`"*

Are those folders all named `target`? (In that case everything is allright).

*"I have imported a `Java` project"* feat. *"Project is a `maven project`"*

Try importing it as a Maven Project `File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects` then browse to the root folder of the Maven project that contains the `pom.xml`. Eclipse will then be able to handle the rest (like setting the correct folders as source/test folders, building the buildpath etc. )

Comment: Yes, these are target folders

Comment: Alright so faar so good, this looks like that project is a standard Maven project then - If you import it as a Maven Project to eclipse - eclipse will know (based on the defined Maven structures) that the sources are placed under `/main/java/src` and compilation output from the Maven build will be placed under `/target/classes` (both one times per Maven Module/ Project). Eclipse will include the classes under `/target/classes` of each Module/ Project to your buildpath.

Comment: Note that if you just "need" the other Project (say JUnit) rather than having a need to change/ rebuild it you would just have a dependency to that other project from within your own Maven project to get the required `.jar`s rather than all of the projects sources.

Comment: I have converted it to maven project using "convert to maven project option". So it is already imported, then how to resolve it.

Comment: @neel lets quickly make sure i understand you correctly: I assume you have one or more Maven project(s) somewhere on your disc (each having a subfolder `/target` somewhere inside it) which you want to be able to use - is that correct? In that case you would just need to Import the existing Maven project - without any conversions.

Comment: (I dont know about the possibility to convert to a Maven Project but I assume this is only possible if Eclipse does not recognize something as Maven project - most oftenly because it is none :))

Comment: or asked simpler: Where did you get the Project you imported? :) (If it is available for me feel free to post a link so i can explain a bit better what you have there and if you realy want to import it as a Maven project into eclipse or rather have your own Maven project with a dependency to that projects build output :))

Comment: If I am importing again, it is giving me the error that project is already imported. And yes you are correct that I have one or more maven projects in the same project.

Comment: It is difficult for me to share the link.

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot start a chat from within the company but to not loose any source i recomend to quickly start a new Eclipse instance and create a new workspace - then import the project again (once imported to eclipse you would need to delete it ... afaik its possible to delete it without deleting anything non-eclipse on the disk but i dont want to guarantee it :))

Comment: then dont share it it should still be possible :)

Comment: I however recomend to quickly read about Maven itself if you dont know much about it as well as Eclipse and Maven since for eclipse there is this plugin i dont know about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061094/importing-maven-project-into-eclipse (it however works for any maven project i ever had to import as maven project - then build and run it unless it was misconfigured o.ä.)