# Checking out hierarchical Maven project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn

I have checked out using subversion/subclipse a hierarchical maven project into my Eclipse project.

At first it is a plain folder structure, then I **right click->Configure..->Convert to Maven Project**.

Now the top node is a Maven project, however all the sub nodes are not recognised as maven projects. I have tried Maven->install and nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing maven project into eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061094/importing-maven-project-into-eclipse)

Comment: The top answer on this other thread is really too old and not recommended any more. So although it's a duplicate, this one will get more recent/better answers.

Comment: no that link does not address my problem. I found out the solution (posted below)

Answer (score 1):

You have to import the projects as [maven projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061094/importing-maven-project-into-eclipse).

> just right-click the package explorer and Import... > Maven projects
>   to import an existing maven project into Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I realise the mistake was that I checked out one level too high. Instead of checking out the root node, I checked out the folder above it.

So in that case Eclipse created a POM file for me for that directory, which confused me into thinking that was the parent POM.

Notice how there is a question mark on the top level POM? It is not in SVN yet.