# How to open an existing maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I need to open a maven project left by my predecessor.

Its file structure is as follows:

```
.settings (folder)
src (folder)
target (folder)
.classpath (file)
.project (file)
pom.xml (file)
```

How should I open this project using the Eclipse installed on my PC?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this answer: [Importing maven project into eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2061645/1248974)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- install maven plug-ins in your eclipse
- import project > Existing Maven Projects(or you can import as general project and convert to maven project)

Comment: Thank you. You solved my issue.