# How to convert hadoop source code to support Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, maven-3

I want to use hadoop source code in eclipse .I imported in neon eclipse as a maven project but I got too much error.What I should do ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing maven project into eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061094/importing-maven-project-into-eclipse)

Comment: no It is not similar,