# Eclipse + Maven modules gives errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, module

I am trying to get abstraction to work with Maven modules (https://bukkit.org/threads/support-multiple-minecraft-versions-with-abstraction-maven.115810/).

I keep getting errors like "The import eu.taigacraft.importer cannot be resolved" although I have the correct dependency in my pom.

I've tried solving them myself with some stackoverflow topics but I couln't figure it out. I have the sollowing set up:

[image]

Java Build Path -> Source: core/Plugin/src/main/java and core/Plugin/src/test/java

How can I properly create Maven modules without getting these annoying errors?

**Edit:**

I have found the problem. Eclipse searches for the dependencies in the main pom.xml instead of the pom.xml in the module which causes it to be unable to resolve imports. How can I fix that?

Comment: Don't post (1) images without the same content as text or (2) off-site links. Your question needs to be self-contained.

Comment: @chrylis Edited

Answer (score 0):

Import the root module as project in Eclipse it will index them correctly. here is how https://stackoverflow.com/a/36242422/175554