# Import large GitHub java project to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, github

I wanted to import the [following](https://github.com/json-iterator/java) GitHub project to eclipse, and I did it like [that](https://github.com/collab-uniba/socialcde4eclipse/wiki/How-to-import-a-GitHub-project-into-Eclipse). The problem is that I get many errors that look like this:

```
The import X cannot be rsolved
```

when `X` is some libaray (for example: `javassist, com.google`). I can solve some of those errors by adding relevant jar files, but there are errors which are more difficult to solve. Also, it doesn't seem like a good way for solving it anyway.
How can I import a project from GitHub to Eclipse without getting those errors?

Comment: You need to [Maven-ize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5611033/2970947); I **see** a `pom.xml`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I tried "Configure → Convert to Maven Project", but it doesn't solve all the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to create the `.project` and `.classpath` files for Eclipse. Then import the project via Eclipse. All required libraries should then be on the classpath.

Here's the resulting `.classpath` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java" output="target/test-classes" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/javassist/javassist/3.21.0-GA/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.5/jackson-annotations-2.8.5.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.5/jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.5/jackson-core-2.8.5.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/openjdk/jmh/jmh-core/1.17.3/jmh-core-1.17.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.6/jopt-simple-4.6.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.2/commons-math3-3.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/openjdk/jmh/jmh-generator-annprocess/1.17.3/jmh-generator-annprocess-1.17.3.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

As you can see, Maven takes care of adding quite a few dependenices to your classpath.

Once the files are generated, I find the most convenient way to get Java projects that live within
Git repositories into Eclipse to use this approach:

- Open the Git Repositories View (Window → Show View → Other → Git → Git Repositories)
- Select 'Add an existing local Git Repository to this view'
- Select the location where you cloned the repository to locally
- Right click the repository in the Git Repositories View and select 'Import Projects'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36242422/2970947

Comment: Yes, you're right the Maven eclipse plugin is retired, see official information here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/
I guess in many projects it is still working as expected though.

Comment: I used it for entirely too long myself, the new way is better; because you can edit the pom and update maven dependencies without regenerating the `.project`

Answer (score 1):

I just import this project without any erros. I'm using Eclipse EE (Oxygen Release 4.7.0).  Here's what I did:

- Checked out the code using git from command line, like the following: `git clone https://github.com/json-iterator/java.git`
- Then, from Eclipse, Go to File -> Import... -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects, and locate the folder named "java" and click "Finish".

That's it, wait a few seconds and the project will be imported.