# ChromeDriver does not start through CMD with "testng.xml"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cmd, testng

I was trying to run a TestNG.xml file from CMD but there are no errors shown and it seems that ChromeDriver is not starting.

**Note**: if i go to Eclipse -> right click on testng.xml -> run as TestNG suite it will work perfectly.

1. Below is the message i get when executing through cmd.
   [image]
2. The bat file contains:

   `java -cp "D:\Java Applications\WebDriverProject\lib*;D:\Java Applications\WebDriverProject\bin" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
   pause`
3. The testng.xml contains:

[image]

4. The project structure from eclipse is:
   [image]

Comment: Where is the package declaration in your code?

Comment: Sorry, the image captured by me does not include the package declaration, but the declaration is in the code (just a little bit higher).

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: You need to include the path to the compiled test classes in the classpath also. Classes would be inside the target folder...

Comment: @IonutzAsaftei - Any reason why you are resorting to running tests via `java -cp` on a maven project (i noticed you have a `pom.xml` in your project) instead of just using `mvn clean test` ?

Comment: Hi @Grasshopper , could you tell me how to do it please (an example would help a lot) ?

Comment: Hello @KrishnanMahadevan , i wanted to run it through TestNG (it's more used in IT industry around here) but you can tell me also how to do it in Maven through CMD (important thing is to make it work). Thank you !

Comment: @IonutzAsaftei Hey, I figured it out finally. My proposed solution is below, please check.

Answer (score 0):

**Running your tests using Maven (Recommended way)**

From your screenshot I am inferring that yours is a maven project. Maven is a build tool that helps with building java code, running tests etc., in an easy fashion. But it looks like you haven't imported your project into eclipse as a Maven project.

So if you would like to run your tests via Maven, you would need to do the following :

1. Remove your project from the workspace (delete it from the workspace but not from the file system). Refer [here](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-42b.htm) to learn how to do it.
2. Now remove the following files from your project folder manually :

   1. `.settings` (I think this should be a folder)
   2. `.classpath`
   3. `.project`
      If you have already setup Maven properly in your machine (Refer [here](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/) to learn how to do that), you can easily clean up the eclipse related files by opening up a command prompt, using `cd` command to navigate into your project directory such that `dir pom.xml` lists the `pom.xml` and then running the command `mvn eclipse:clean`
3. Now refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36242422/679824) StackOverFlow post to learn how to import a maven project into eclipse and import the project into eclipse.
4. You now have your project configured properly so that eclipse recognizes your project as a maven project. Now to run the tests from the command prompt, (refer to surefire documentation to learn how to add surefire plugin to your pom file) run `mvn clean test`

**Running your tests from command prompt**

For running your project without using any build tool, you just need to append `target\test-classes` and `target\classes` directories to your `java -cp` command run it. So your modified batch file can look like below

```
java -cp "D:\Java Applications\WebDriverProject\lib*;D:\Java Applications\WebDriverProject\bin;D:\Java Applications\WebDriverProject\target\classes;D:\Java Applications\WebDriverProject\target\test-classes" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
pause
```

On a side note, please add `verbose="2"` or higher to the `<suite>` tag in your suite xml file, so that it shows you what error occurred.

Also please ensure that your `testng.xml` resides under `src\test\resources` folder (you can very well create this folder if it doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

well try to put TestNG.jar file https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng/6.7 and jcommander jar https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/jcommander/1.7 in lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. First of all, how you set up the classpath environment is crucial. The very first path must be a path to your project bin folder (where the .class files are found). I will just paste what my classpath environment looks like:

```
set classpath=C:\eclipse-2018\ACR_Tests\bin;C:\Selenium_dependencies\*;C:\TestNG\plugins\*
```

Set TestNG classpath:

```
java -classpath %classpath% org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Note:
I have a "Selenium dependencies" folder also added to the classpath, this is a folder containing more selenium libraries, including chromedriver.jar

Download the zipped package:

> selenium-chrome-driver JAR 3.12.0

It contains the dependencies that you need.

https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver/3.12.0/source-code

Extract all to a folder. In my case I called it "Selenium_dependencies".

Also, for TestNG libraries I'm using 7.0.0 release which you can download here:

http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/zipped/

My testng.xml is like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="P1.ACR_Server"/> <!-- package.class -->
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Also - ensure that you have client-combined.jar included on the build path.

The build path should contain these libraries:

[image]