# Eclipse/NetBeans and Maven integeration

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, netbeans

I'm going to ask about Eclipse/NetBeans and Maven, but first let me state my **higher goal** for which I'm only guessing Eclipse/NetBeans and Maven will be a good combination.

I'm an experienced programmer and computer science tutor in several languages, but I'm learning Java for the first time. I'm helping a student learn it along with me.

I'm most used to Emacs, and I got the JDEE mode working together with Maven quite nicely.

My student finds Emacs unwieldy and wants to use something else. He only knows Atom so far, but that doesn't seem very well integrated with Java yet. Eclipse or NetBeans seem like good bets. (Any known differences, especially for a beginner learning Java?)

My student and I would like to work from the same repo. Because I have a Maven project working nicely with Emacs, I'd like him to be able to work on the same project in Eclipse or NetBeans.

Can I get some suggestions about how to go about this?

I already tried importing my project into Eclipse, but it doesn't work. I go to the importer, then the Maven section, and try to select my project directory. The importer shows the pom.xml but it's grayed-out and can't be selected.

Alternatively, going back to my **higher goal** which is for my student and I to be able to collaborate, with me on Emacs and him on something more modern and easy for him to assimilate ... a different idea altogether, perhaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing maven project into eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2061094/5221149)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetBeans treat maven project as first class citizen. You can open a maven project as is without installing any plugins. That'll be the easiest way for you to forget setup and start coding.