# Eclipse Maven project and GIT

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

I have Eclipse Maven Java project on my first PC. I have committed this project to GIT repository with directory structure:

src/main/java
pom.xml

What is the right way to get project in another PC like Eclipse Java Maven one?

Should I start new Maven project, go through all initial settings and later somehow checkout git project into current project directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing maven project into eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061094/importing-maven-project-into-eclipse)

Comment: In the _Git Repositories_ view right-click the repository and choose _Import Projects..._.

Comment: @azro Well, the question is a duplicate, but the answers are unfortunately all outdated (written before the so-called _Smart Import_ has been introduced).

Comment: @howlger Can you please add the *Smart Import* as an answer to that question? Lets update that instead of adding inconsistent duplicates.

Comment: @omajid That question is not about importing from Git. Therefore I gave a [slightly different answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53421870/6505250).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend one of the following two:

- In the ***Git Repositories*** view **right-click** the repository node, one folder or multiple selected folders in the *Working Tree* and choose ***Import Projects...***
- ***File > Projects from File System...*** and choose the directory of the local Git repository

Answer (score 0):

I follow this way:

**Git**:

- Clone my project in a local directory

**Eclipse:**

- Click **File** menu
- Choose **Import...**
- Click **Maven** and choose **Existing Maven Projects** and click **Next**
- Set **Root Directory** to cloned *project directory* from **Browse...** and check **pom.xml** in **Projects:** section and finally Click **Finish** button.

Done!