# How to import maven nested project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have tried to import a nested maven project into Eclipse, and I need help.

```
-ProjectName
 -pom
 -.project
 -license
 -.git
 -modules
  -api1
   -pom
   -.project
   -src/main/java/net/company/project
  -api2
  -api3
```

The API's all use each other and classes from separate API's have the same package declaration (don't know how that works)

Basically when I import the topmost folder, I get a bunch of projects in eclipse, one being parent and all others symbolizing the api folders.

Then all of my code recommendations don't work because "the package is not on the project's build path."

Don't know if this is the right way to fix the issue above, but I select a package (api1/src for example) from the parent project and choose build path > add as source folder which makes all my code recommendations work again.

However, it breaks all the package declarations in 200 classes, from
`package net.company.project.subpackage`
to `package main.java.net.company.project.subpackage`

I can't fix all those classes! What should I do?
I'm pretty inexperienced with Eclipse and Maven, please help!

Thank you for your time
Side note: all of the maven dependencies and poms seem to work fine

Comment: Did you try: [Importing `maven` project into `eclipse`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061094/importing-maven-project-into-eclipse) ?

Comment: Yes that is how I imported the project, can anyone help please