# How do use these source files with java file name?

Tags: java

c++,python but have no experience working with java files. I found some tools suporting my work in python but they are in java .This is the code source

https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-gtfs-realtime-from-siri-cli/tree/master/src/main

Can anyone give some guidance on how to build or run these source files.

thanks

Comment: Clone github into your local and build using maven , use any Java IDE  here 
 are few inputs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061094/importing-maven-project-into-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

just clone the source from GitHub and import it to java IDE example; Eclipse, IntelliJ, Netbeans. to run just click the run button.
https://www.wikihow.com/Run-Java-Program-in-Eclipse for eclipse
you can also use command prompt without installing some IDE but make sure your device already installed java

> 1. open a command prompt window and go to the directory where you saved the java program (MyFirstJavaProgram.java). Assume it's C:.
> 2. Type 'javac MyFirstJavaProgram.java' and press enter to compile your code. If there are no errors in your code, the command prompt will take you to the next line (Assumption: The path variable is set).
> 3. Now, type ' java MyFirstJavaProgram ' to run your program.
> 4. You will be able to see the result printed on the window.

Answer (score 0):

- Get these sources: [clone](https://help.github.com/en/articles/cloning-a-repository) the project
- The project is build with [Maven](http://maven.apache.org), so you need to install it.
- Dig into pom.xml (Maven build configation file) and find out, which version of Java it requires
- Install porper version of [Java SDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
- Armed with Maven documentation, build an executable file out of the sources