# How I can open & execute a maven project with eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

[image]

How I can open a maven project software ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing Maven project into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061094/importing-maven-project-into-eclipse)

Comment: @Kaneda That's technically a duplicate question, but the accepted answer is a classic case for the feature-in-progress of marking something as technically outdated. `eclipse:eclipse` has been dead for a decade, and only Import is correct.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Oh okay, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

The process should be relatively simple. File -> Import --> Maven --> 'Existing Maven Project'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know fort eclipse but it won't be that different from IntelliJ. Import project as a Maven project, and in eclipse, à right click on the main java file then run should work.

Or type mvn install in eclipse terminal ,  and you'll have  jar file you can launch.